# Problem with getElementbyId

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I'm having a problem with getElementbyId as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function show_links(locale) {

        var box = document.getElementById(locale);

        if(box.style.display == "none") { 
            box.style.display = "inline";
        } 
         else { 

            box.style.display = "none";
        }

    }
    //-->
</script>

<div class="link"><strong><a href="javascript:show_links(test);">Test</a></strong></div>
<div class="test"> Blah blah blah. This content comes and goes. </div>
```

So there you have the code. When I click the link "Test", it should hide the "blah blah blah text". When clicked again, it should show. However, I have an odd problem. I processed the code through a debugger, and it seems that the line `var box = document.getElementById(locale);` is not working correctly. `box` is being set to null. Can anyone theorize why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems. First the critical ones:

1. The value you are passing to the `show_links` function is the variable `test`. This is equal to `undefined` so it isn't going to match anything.
2. The element you are trying to find by its **id** doesn't have an id. It has only a class.

You need to give the element you are trying to match an id and pass a **string** instead of an undefined value.

Then the lesser issues.

1. You are testing the inline display style property, but you aren't setting it by default. As a rule of thumb, it is better to twiddle the `className` property, and have your styles defined in a stylesheet.
2. You are using a javascript pseudo-URI instead of [progressive enhancement](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/).
3. You have [comments wrapped around the inside of the script](http://dorward.me.uk/www/comments-cdata/). At **best**, these are pointless.
4. You are twiddling a div between `inline` and `none`, but the default display value for a div is `block`. There are reasons to have a div styled inline, but most of the time you should be using another element.

Comment: +1. Even disregarding the benefits of progressive enhancement, `javascript:` pseudo-URIs were broken and obsolete the day they were born and never, ever should ever be used in a page. Ever.

Answer (score 0):

```
javascript:show_links(test);
```

`test` is an unknown identifer. Where did you define it? Did you mean to feed a string?

```
<div class="test"> Blah blah blah. This content comes and goes. </div>
```

There is no element with an id of `test` in this line. Use the proper attribute `id`.